# Is there a way to control the inner behavior of queues in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm making a service that consumes a specific queue in RabbitMQ.

In the work up to this point, I don't need to worry about the internal behavior of the queue, I just need to properly process the value the queue delivers.

But I would like to know more advanced knowledge.

If too many services send messages to the queue I'm consuming, the queue could burst.

To prevent this I would have to multiplex the queue or make it scalable, is there a way to do this?

Should I create multiple queues with the same function and implement it so that consumer services can choose which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Queues are single-threaded, so in order to scale things up, there are some plugins that help you do this.

We are using `x-consistent-hash` ([Ref](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange)) but there are also other plugins like [rabbitmq-sharding](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding)

Consistent-hash is a technique that lets you create multiple queues for consuming events coming from an exchange. so you can be sure that you can use all CPU cores of a server. besides, it lets you add more queues later on.
lern more about consitent-hashing [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing).